# Python - Pygame. How can I disable/root mouse movement when sprites collide?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I have this snippet of code:

```
end_hist_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, end_walls, False)

for end in end_hist_list:
    end_sound.play()
    #now need to root position of mouse/or disable mouse movement
```

So when that sprite (player) collides with end_wall, I need for mouse to not be able to move, to just root in that position (when that collision happened). But I can't find any function that would let disable or root mouse. I tried reseting position to end_walls coordinates, but then it resets near that sprite, but not on top of it. I think there should be some simple way to do that, I just might not see it. Any suggestions?

P.S. mouse controls player sprite (in end spritecollide it is `self`) like this:

```
def update(self):
    """ Update player position """
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    self.rect.x = pos[0]
    self.rect.y = pos[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as `mouse.get_pos`, there is a [`mouse.set_pos`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_pos). You could use this to keep returning the mouse to the appropriate position when the player tries to move it away. Effectively, you reverse the current `update`:

```
pygame.mouse.set_pos(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
```

Alternatively, you could just stop dealing with mouse events. If the cursor is visible it will still move around, but the game will ignore it.